# Adding PostGIS query layer says Query class name is invalid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-10.2, query-layer

I am having issues with adding postgis query layers in ArcMAP 10.2.2.3552, not doing anything special just adding a layer, this works in 10.2.1 so I don't know if its a bug or something

Also this error only happens when adding a query layer from a database over the network using ip address, the same database in the local install has no issues

[image: error image]

Comment: Could you show us the structure of the table? ArcMap is very finicky about how you structure your postgis tables. For example, it doesn't like any uppercase column names for some reason...

Comment: yeah thing is it works in a previous version, we are testing in the following days with Collate because in Postgis it is using "XXX.XXXX" and if we changed this to "English,XX" it works. So maybe dot notation is the culprit here.

Comment: OK managed to solve things, apparently username cant be longer than 8 characters or have ".", adding this here just in case someone else has same issues

Comment: wow.. that's interesting... and weird! Please place your answer in the answer area and accept it. Answered questions are marked differently and more legible for future readers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for future reference,

Username was giving issues if it was longer that 8 characters and if it contained ".", I really don't know why but reducing username length to 8 characters has solved the query layers issues I was experiencing, probably didn't work in previous version as IT used postgres user to test

Comment: Ouch that was really a nasty one good catch!

Comment: However the 8 character limit seem to have been set to something longer an more reasonable as of  version 10.3.1. The dot still cause issue.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference in case anyone else has the same misfortune, I got the same error message trying to add a SQL Spatial table and found that you need to "Check" the name (ISqlWorkspace::CheckDatasetName) before using it.  https://badarcgis.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/query-class-name-is-invalid/